# Will theme affects the color change in different devices?

Tags: android

I have set the theme as DeviceDefaultTheme.Light for my app, but now what the problem is when I was running my app in marshmallow os device and kitkat os device I am seeing the color difference in both the devices I was in struck.
Please help me to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are using a theme called `DeviceDefaultTheme` and wonder why colors change with device and version? I'd say this is rather expected. KitKat and Marshmallow do have different styles.

Comment: No, I am using common styles for all the versions of devices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that older androids have different system object style (think about material design and older designs), so the theme color is, in the end, the least of the problems.